# How to convert multiple csv files into array faster?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, csv

I have a folder containing 9000 CSV files. Each file has 5000 rows and 12 columns. For Deep learning training purposes, I need to convert this whole file( all files ) into an array of shape (9000,5000,12). I am using this code for my work:

```
path=mypath+'//'+li[0]+'.csv' #li is a list containing the filenames, this is for a filtering purpose, please ignore this  
df=pd.read_csv(path)
a=np.array(df)

path=mypath+'//'+li[1]+'.csv'   
df=pd.read_csv(path)
arr=np.array(df)
a=np.stack((a,arr))
for filename in li[2:]:
    path=mypath+'//'+filename+'.csv'   
    df=pd.read_csv(path) 
    arr=np.array(df)
    if(arr.shape[0]!=4999):
        
        continue
    
    a=np.append(a,[arr],axis=0)
```

So, basically, I am converting each CSV file into a data frame, and then converting the data frame into an array. Finally stacking the arrays together.

This process is taking too much time. Only 2000 files converted in 1h. Is there any faster approach that can serve my purpose?

***Sorry for my bad coding format, I was just doing the roughs and it took too much time***

Comment: `df.values()` will give you the 2D (numpy) array of values inside the DataFrame. It's probably faster and less memory consuming than making a new array with `np.array(df)`.

Comment: Appending to an array will resize that array each time. If you can, preallocate the complete (empty) 3D array, then insert the 2D arrays in-place with the right indices into that 3D array. Be aware that memory may become an issue with these array dimensions.

Comment: 9000 CSV files with (integer? floating point?) data? If you have any control over the input files, consider using a proper binary format, such as HDF5. That will make things *much* faster, and considerably better if there are floating point numbers and metadata involved.

Comment: Check out [Read multiple csv files (size mxm) and load as an n dimensional array (size nxmxm) (not concatenate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57283513/read-multiple-csv-files-size-mxm-and-load-as-an-n-dimensional-array-size-nxmx)

Comment: Note that 2000 files in an hour is not that bad: one afternoon of doing something else in the meantime and all your data have been read. Just make sure to store the final 3D array in a proper format (e.g., the aforementioned HDF5 could work) for a next time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read multiple csv files (size mxm) and load as an n dimensional array (size nxmxm) (not concatenate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57283513/read-multiple-csv-files-size-mxm-and-load-as-an-n-dimensional-array-size-nxmx)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments. Yes, my file has only floating point numbers. The attached qus does not have any answer on converting into 3d array. Would you please explain a bit more about the hdf5 format idea?

Comment: First off: do you have control over the input files? Otherwise, I'll just deal with the "9000 input CSVs" situation.

Comment: I'm not sure why the suggested duplicate does not solve your problem: `a = np.asarray([pd.read_csv(f).values for f in filenames])` will yield a 3D array of the input 2D CSV files. Perhaps you want the dimensions to be different? Then `np.rollaxis` could help.

Comment: Explaining more about HDF 5 would make this a tutorial. I just mention it, but a full explanation wouldn't be a (straightforward) answer to your question. But you can have a look yourself; start for example with reading up on [h5py](https://www.h5py.org/). Storing (nD) arrays of (floating point) numbers in a HDF5 file is generally much better than storing them in a CSV file: you get more options for dimensions (1, 2, 3, ...) instead of (always) just 2 (CSV), more security about avoiding precision loss (it stores the actual binary data, not an ASCII representation), and is generally faster.

Comment: Hey @00 Thanks a lot!!! My isuue is solved by preallocating the array. It took only 3 minutes to convert!!!!! Thanks a loootttt!

Answer (score 0):

Finally Solved the issue. Thanks to @0 0
I have preallocated the array and it took only 3 minutes to complete my work!

```
os.chdir("E://2-1//reserach//tanvir sir//datasets//ECGDataDenoised//filter//")
from glob import glob
import numpy as np
strain = glob("*.csv")



arr=np.zeros(( 9061,4999,12  ))
i=0
for filename in strain:
      
    df=pd.read_csv(filename) 
    
    arr[i]=df.values
    i=i+1
```

The final shape of the array is (9061,4999,12) , as I wanted!

Comment: I hope you don't relying on any specific ordering of the files and your zeroth dimension.

Comment: You can make things a bit more flexible by change `9061` to `len(strain)`. And use `for (i, filename) in enumerate(strain):` to remove the `i=0` and `i=i+1` lines: tends to be clearer as to your intention (the index of the filenames matches the first index in `arr`.